# Extracting specific files within directory - Windows

Tags: python

I am running a loop which needs to access circa 200 files in the directory.

In the folder - the format of the files range as follows:

1. Excel_YYYYMMDD.txt
2. Excel_YYYYMMDD_V2.txt
3. Excel_YYYYMMDD_orig.txt

I only need to extract the first one - that is YYYYMMDD.txt, and nothing else

I am using glob.glob to access the directory where i specified my path name as follows:

```
path = "Z:\T\Al8787\Box\EAST\OT\\ABB files/2019/*[0-9].txt"
```

However the code also extracts the .Excel_YYYYMMDD_orig.txt file too

Appreciate assistance on how to modify code to only extract desired files.

Comment: Should it be: `path = "Z:\T\C0823\NewYork\EAST\Ops\\ABB files/2019/[0-9]*.txt"`

Comment: @QuangHoang, don't you need to add `Excel` to the file name pattern? So that you get: `path = "Z:\T\C0823\NewYork\EAST\Ops\\ABB files/2019/Excel_[0-9]*.txt"`

Comment: @Perplexabot True, I didn't see `Excel` in the post. Thanks.

Comment: @QuangHoang, isnt the * a wild card and therefore extract everything after the date? Or is it the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cheap way to do it (and by cheap I mean probably not the best/cleanest method):

```
import glob
l = glob.glob("Excel_[0-9]*.txt")
```

This will get you:

```
>>> print(l)
['Excel_19900717_orig.txt', 'Excel_19900717_V2.txt', 'Excel_19900717.txt']
```

Now filter it yourself:

```
nl = [x for x in l if "_orig" not in x and "_V2" not in x]
```

This will give you:

```
>>> print(nl)
['Excel_19900717.txt']
```

The reason for manually filtering through our glob is because the glob library does not support regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `^Excel_[0-9]{8}\.txt` as the file matching regex.

Comment: {8} means exactly 8 digits in [0-9]. And, `.` (dot) means any single character matching and `\.` means matching exactly one dot.

Comment: Acutally @Mahmood Al Rayhan, this isnt working. IT does not pick up any files

Comment: @MahmoodAlRayhan, the glob library does not support regex, unfortunately.